# Динамический размер шрифта, на основе количества текста и размеров блока

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть код:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Aquarelle";
  padding: 1cm;
  margin: 0px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

table td {
  font-size: 70pt;
  padding: 0 7%;
  min-width: 29cm;
  max-width: 21cm;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="white" lang="RU">
  <div class="Section1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">Самой красивой, умной, нежной, любимой маме! </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при увеличении количества символов в тексте, таблица не росла по высоте (оставалась фиксированной `min-width: 29cm; max-width: 21cm;`), при этом должен уменьшаться шрифт. Нужно, чтобы размер шрифта был максимально возможным, в выделенных ему границах (отступы 7% слева и справа).

Реально ли на чистом CSS ? Если нет, то тогда вариант на JS.

Везде нахожу примеры, где под размер экрана всё затачивается.

Comment: `font-size: XXvw`

Comment: @HamSter это по ширине экрана. это не то

Answer (score 3):

К сожалению, решить вашу задачу только на CSS, пока невозможно. Но, на помощь приходит JavaScript. Сама функция небольшая и понятная, но производительность всё же оставляет желать лучшего.

Текст постоянно находится в границах блока и видим полностью всегда. Изменяется только размер шрифта, исходя из длины слов и количества строк.

```js
/* Функция пересчёта размера шрифта */
function fGummaFontSize() {
  /* Увеличиваем размер шрифта, до появления прокрутки */
  while (this.scrollHeight <= this.clientHeight || this.scrollWidth <= this.clientWidth) {
    this.style.fontSize = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(this).fontSize) + 2 + "px";
  }
  /* Уменьшаем размер шрифта, пока прокрутка не исчезнет */
  while ( this.scrollHeight > this.clientHeight || this.scrollWidth > this.clientWidth ) {
    this.style.fontSize = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(this).fontSize) - 1 + "px";
  }
}

/* Функция обхода всех элементов с нужным классом */
function fGummaResizeAll() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".gumma").forEach(el => fGummaFontSize.call(el));
}

document.querySelectorAll(".gumma").forEach(el => el.addEventListener("input", fGummaFontSize));
window.onload = fGummaResizeAll; // Запуск после загрузки контента
window.onresize = fGummaResizeAll; // Запуск при изменении размеров окна и контейнеров
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; } body { background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png") 0% 0% no-repeat rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 100vh; display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; justify-content: space-around; justify-content: space-evenly; align-items: center; }

 /* Большая часть свойств критически важна! */
.gumma {
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  word-break: normal;
  line-break: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: none;
  hyphens: none;
  height: 160px;
  width: 30%;
  background: rgba(240, 240, 240);
}
```

```html
<div class="gumma" contenteditable>Ура!</div>
<div class="gumma" contenteditable>Самой красивой, умной, нежной, любимой маме!</div>
<div class="gumma" contenteditable>Текст с самымидлиннымисловамибезпробеловипереносов - лучший подарок!</div>
```

> Примечание: Атрибут `contenteditable` добавлен исключительно для интерактивности и наглядности и необязателен. Также его использование, в некоторых случаях, ломает работу функции (например, при вставке блока текста из буфера обмена, но не посимвольного ввода). При изменении текста через скрипт, функция работает нормально.

Comment: класс! Поигрался с текстом, добавляя количество слов, фраз. За рамки контейнера ничего не выходит и чтобы поместиться в контейнер просто уменьшается размер шрифта. Здорово, мне понравилось.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: на куче площадок этот вопрос висит годами, а решение или не гуглится или находятся простыни кода, которые решают задачу лишь частично. В общем, больше для себя любимого накодил))

Answer (score 1):

Вот прям чтобы не вылезало за пределы height, насколько мне известно, только css мало. Благо на JS библиотек предостаточно. 
Однако, есть еще интересный вариант с svg, правда надо поиграть с координатами и viewBox (попробуйте viewport браузера подергать в примере) 
[Клац](https://codepen.io/Ell_Sharko/pen/vPKKPa)

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 56 18">
  <text x="0" y="15">Fit Me</text>
</svg>
```

Источник: [csstricks](https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/)