# Почему все строки многострочного текста кроме последней смещены на один символ влево?

Tags: svg

**1) Почему все строки многострочного текста кроме последней смещены на один символ влево?**

```html
<svg xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" baseProfile="full" height="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 448 320" width="100%">
  <rect fill="#FFFFFF" height="320" stroke="none" width="448"/>
  <g id="root" transform="translate(0,0)">
    <g id="graph" transform="translate(64,64)">
      <rect id="background" width="320" height="192" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0" fill="#e0e0e0"/>
      <g id="history" transform="translate(0, 14.666666666666668)" stroke-width="none" font-family="Consolas" font-size="12pt" fill="#000000">
        <text x="320" text-anchor="end">
          <tspan>Abcdefabcd</tspan>
          <tspan x="320" dy="1em">Abcd F</tspan>
          <tspan x="320" dy="1em">Abcd F</tspan>
          <tspan x="320" dy="1em">Abcd F</tspan>
          <tspan x="275.8333333333333" dy="2em" text-anchor="middle">Abc</tspan>
          <tspan x="320" dy="1em">Abcd F</tspan>
          <tspan x="320" dy="1em">Abcd F</tspan>
          <tspan x="320" dy="1em">Abcd F</tspan>
        </text>
        <line stroke="#FFFF00" stroke-width="1.0" x1="231.66666666666666" y1="14.666666666666668" x2="258.1666666666667" y2="14.666666666666668"/>
        <line stroke="#00FF00" stroke-width="1.0" x1="231.66666666666666" y1="29.333333333333336" x2="258.1666666666667" y2="29.333333333333336"/>
        <line stroke="#FF0000" stroke-width="1.0" x1="231.66666666666666" y1="44.0" x2="258.1666666666667" y2="44.0"/>
        <line stroke="#808000" stroke-width="1.0" x1="231.66666666666666" y1="93.83333333333334" x2="258.1666666666667" y2="93.83333333333334"/>
        <line stroke="#008000" stroke-width="1.0" x1="231.66666666666666" y1="109.66666666666669" x2="258.1666666666667" y2="109.66666666666669"/>
        <line stroke="#800000" stroke-width="1.0" x1="231.66666666666666" y1="125.50000000000001" x2="258.1666666666667" y2="125.50000000000001"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно сместить весь текст (кроме последней строки) влево на ширину одного символа (используются только моноширинные шрифты).

**2) Но как правильно вычислить размер одного символа шрифта для n-го размера?** На данный момент вычислил только приблизительные коэффициенты для шрифта Consolas, но они не являются точными. **Есть ли универсальное решение?**

Comment: @MaximLensky, спасибо. Это не "лишнее", это автоматически добавленное при генерации SVG. Я строю SVG по параметрам, которые указал пользователь (не параметры svg, а, например, параметры графика: высота, ширина, цвет осей и т.д.), поэтому просто взять и задать жестко параметры элементов я не могу, они должны вычисляться (отсюда такие страшные цифры).

Comment: таку штуку можно рисовать руками - без редактора

Comment: @MaximLensky, все можно сделать руками, но сейчас все ленивые и хотят, чтобы тот или иной процесс был автоматизирован. :)

Comment: @ioprst посмотрите [ещё один ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1084428/28748) `@UModeL` он как-то остался без внимания, а зря, может этот ответ натолкнет на свежие мысли, как можно автоматизировать, подстраивать и умещать различные тексты в контейнер с фиксированными размерами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Inline и "пионерское расстояние"

> В данном случае рассматривается проблема с SVG, но всё это справедливо и для HTML.

Сразу отвечу на вопрос: смещение происходит потому, что между inline-тегами (в даном случае это `<tspan>`) есть перенос строки, который интерпретируется, как пробельный символ.

Для борьбы с этим явлением, чаще всего применяют один из трёх способов:

---

#### Способ первый - правильный

Не нужно, при работе с SVG, пренебрегать CSS. Во-первых, всё равно без стилей не обойтись. Во-вторых, CSS имеет довольно большую гибкость в выборке по селекторам. В-третьих, стили для этого и предназначены. В-четвёртых, inline-стили - моветон, ибо сложнее прописывать и , что самое главное, их ничем не перебить, т.к. они имеют высший приоритет.

Поэтому, убираем `style` из тегов и пишем в блоке `<style>` или в файле CSS следующее:

```css
#history > text { font-size: 0; } /* Задаём нулевой размер шрифта для контейнера */
#history > text > tspan { font-size: 12pt; } /* Задаём нужный размер для текстовых блоков */
```

Т.о. мы "схлопываем" любые символы, находящиеся в блоке с текстом (`<text>`), но вне обёрток `<tspan>` с явно указанным размером шрифта.

---

#### Способ второй - простой и понятный

**Просто** не плодим лишние ненужные символы, а записываем теги в одну строку без переносов:

```
<text><tspan>A</tspan><tspan>Б</tspan><tspan>В</tspan><tspan>Г</tspan><tspan>Д</tspan></text>
```

**Понятно**, что "нет переносов - нет проблем".

---

#### Способ третий - грязный хак

Почему "грязный хак"? "Хак" потому, что не предназначен для такого использования, но работает. А "грязный" из-за того, что прилично засоряет разметку. Несмотря на это, его часто применяли раньше.

Общеизвестно, что тег комментария (`<!-- -->`), как и его содержимое, полностью игнорируются при отображении документа. Поэтому логично сделать перенос именно в этом теге:

```
<text x="320" text-anchor="end">
    <tspan x="320" dy="1em">Abcd F</tspan><!--
 --><tspan x="320" dy="1em">Abcd F</tspan><!--
 --><tspan x="320" dy="1em">Abcd F</tspan><!--
 --><tspan x="320" dy="1em">Abcd F</tspan>
</text>
```

Как видим, подобный подход сильно усложняет зрительное восприятие кода, а переносы делаются как раз для удобочитаемости. Т.о. "поменяли шило на мыло".

---

Еще больше способов борьбы с данной напастью - [«Загадочные отступы» между инлайн-элементами](https://css-live.ru/articles/zagadochnye-otstupy-mezhdu-inlajn-blokami.html)