# Как убрать пустое место между блоками inline-block?

Tags: html, css, inline, white-space

Делаю [сайт](https://luc337.github.io/project/)

Между двумя блоками `div` есть пространство буквально в `1px`, и снизу блока то же самое.

Все margin'ы я обнулил, откуда они взялись и как их убрать, чтобы блоки вплотную стояли?

Знаю, что  можно сделать с помощью float, но хотелось бы оставить `display: inline-block`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.header {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.header__left {
  background-image: url(../images/1.png);
  width: 65%;
  height: 715px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header__right {
  background-image: url(../images/2.png);
  width: 34%;
  height: 715px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__left"></div>
  <div class="header__right"></div>
</div>
<div class="mider">
  <div class="mider__left"></div>
  <div class="mider__right">
    <div class="mider__right-top"></div>
    <div class="mider__right-bot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer__left"></div>
  <div class="footer__right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Почитайте - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1089903/265406 Думаю, будет полезно.

Comment: @UModeL отлично, то что искал!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему все строки многострочного текста кроме последней смещены на один символ влево?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1089717/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2)

Answer (score 3):

Такое может происходить из за ***пустого места в шаблоне HTML***, которое обычно убирается на этапе минификации.

Если она не планируется, то понадобиться самостоятельно убрать пробелы:

```
// как сейчас
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__left"></div>
  <div class="header__right"></div>
</div>

// как следует поменять
<div class="header"><div class="header__left"></div><div class="header__right"></div></div>

// или так (не рекомендую, просто для информации)
<div class="header"
  ><div class="header__left"></div
  ><div class="header__right"></div
></div>

// или так (еще одно извращение)
<div class="header"><!--
  --><div class="header__left"></div><!--
  --><div class="header__right"></div><!--
--></div>
```

Результат после:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рабочий пример:

```css
.header {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.header__left, .header__right {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 45px;
}

.header__left {
  width: 165px;
  background-color: blue;  
}

.header__right {
  width: 135px;
  background-color: green;  
}
```

```html
<div class="header"><div class="header__left"></div><div class="header__right"></div></div>
```

*В случае, когда мы имеем дело с определенными `inline-элементами` может потребоваться дополнительное обнуление свойств `font-size` и `line-height`, которые могут провоцировать нежелательные отступы.*

*Отдельно стоит отметить что у div-элементов `margin` и `padding` по дефолту и так равны нулю, т.е специально обнулять их не требуеться.*

Answer (score 3):

Между элементами появляется пространство, вызванное тем, при написание вы использовали "новую строку", а браузер из этого уже сделал "пробел":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решений несколько, вот те которые могу предложить:

**Выставить родителю `font-size: 0`**

```css
.header {
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* ----- */
  font-size: 0;
}

.header__left {
  background: red;
  width: 65%;
  height: 90vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header__right {
  background: blue;
  width: 34%;
  height: 90vh;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__left"></div>
  <div class="header__right"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Использовать `float: left;`**

```css
.header {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* fix */
.header::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.header__left {
  background: red;
  width: 65%;
  height: 90vh;
  display: inline-block;
  /* ----- */
  float: left;
}

.header__right {
  background: blue;
  width: 34%;
  height: 90vh;
  display: inline-block;
  /* ----- */
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__left"></div>
  <div class="header__right"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Использовать комментарий**

```css
.header {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.header__left {
  background: red;
  width: 65%;
  height: 90vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header__right {
  background: blue;
  width: 34%;
  height: 90vh;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__left"></div><!--
  --><div class="header__right"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Использовать "новые" технологии Flexbox или Grid Layout**

```css
.header {
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* ---- */
  display: flex;
}

.header__left {
  background: red;
  width: 65%;
  height: 90vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header__right {
  background: blue;
  width: 34%;
  height: 90vh;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__left"></div>
  <div class="header__right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Может кому-то не понравился float-left, который по идее не должен использоваться для позиционирования) Еще, можно физически перенести закрывающую `>` на следующую строку, начав следующий блок так: `><div`

Comment: Раньше использовался и всё было "хорошо".. А вот насчёт последнего варианта не знал, интересно.

Comment: Добавлю здесь еще 1 мысль - я слышал, что заминусованные вопросы автоудаляются если нету ответов с рейтингом больше 0. Т.е. кто-то мог выписать ответам по минусу только для того чтобы вопрос побыстрее автоматом удалился (и вам этот -1 вернется при этом).