# Почуму внутрь блока не умещаются в ряд блоки шириной 33,33%?

Tags: css, вёрстка, inline-block

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner" style="border: 1px solid; display:inline-block; height:30px; width:33.33%"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="border: 1px solid; display:inline-block; height:30px; width:33.33%"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="border: 1px solid; display:inline-block; height:30px; width:33.33%"></div>
</div>
```

Cделаем у body

```
body{
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

И все-равно не умещаются! Сделаем блокам border: 0;, сделаем без .wrapper – опять не умещаются. Здесь что-то неправильно.

Как расположить 3 блока во всю ширину с шириной каждого 33,33%?

Comment: Попробуй в wrapper добавить display: flex, flex-wrap: nowrap;

Answer (score 1):

- Во-первых, когда элементы строчные или строчно-блочные, то перенос в разметке считается за пробельный символ и тоже имеет свой размер. У Вас таких переносов два, поэтому задаём для родителя нулевой размер шрифта, а потомкам возвращаем нужный. Почитать подробнее можно [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1089903/265406).
- Во-вторых, без указания `box-sizing: border-box;`, все размеры *border* плюсуются к размерам блока, что тоже не способствует расположению "впритирку".

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.wrapper { font-size: 0; }
.inner { font-size: 16px; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner" style="border: 1px solid; display:inline-block; height:30px; width:33.33%"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="border: 1px solid; display:inline-block; height:30px; width:33.33%"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="border: 1px solid; display:inline-block; height:30px; width:33.33%"></div>
</div>
```