# Нужно уменьшать шрифт в зависимости от кол-ва символов или под размер поля/дива/области

Tags: javascript, масштабирование

https://jsfiddle.net/rsany/sL3ohg2k/6/

```
<div id="id_div">Тут текст должен менять размер в зависимости от кол-ва букв</div>
Сюда мы его вводим: <input type="text" name="tekst" size="43" value="" onKeyUp=" javascript:document.getElementById('id_div').innerHTML = this.value;">
```

Нигде не нашел реализацию, чтобы в реальном времени вводимый человеком текст в форму,
менял свой размер в другом месте. Кажется, что это должно быть не сложно, но я совсем плох в JS, а css с этим не справляется, нашел только изменение шрифта под размер монитора.

Подскажите есть ли простое решение на js, или это настолько сложно что лучше забыть?

Comment: Разберитесь и сделайте по аналогии - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1084428/265406

Comment: Пробовал это использовать, но ничего не получилось. Подскажите, данное решение должно работать в режиме реального времени? Или только после обновления страницы?

Comment: покажите, как Вы использовали это? Должно работать после вызова функции.

Comment: я просто впихивал свой див в див из примера, похоже это работает не так)) Если вы говорите что должно помочь, значит поковыряюсь еще) Спасибо за помощь)

<div class="gumma" contenteditable><div id="id_div"></div>
 <input type="text" name="tekst"  onKeyUp=" javascript:document.getElementById('id_div').innerHTML = this.value;"  >

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rsany/sL3ohg2k/40/  или вот так... тоже ничего не происодит

Answer (score 3):

В голову приходит только манипуляция с `transform: scale`:

```js
let block = document.querySelector('.block');
let span = block.getElementsByTagName("SPAN")[0];

document.querySelector(".text").addEventListener('input', update);

function update() {
  span.innerText = this.value;
  calculate();
}

function calculate() {
  let xScale = block.clientWidth / span.clientWidth;
  let yScale = block.clientHeight / span.clientHeight;
  
  span.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%) scale(' + Math.min(xScale, yScale) + ')';
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.block {
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}
.block > span {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  line-height: 1;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="block"><span></span></div>

Сюда мы его вводим: <input type="text" class="text" size="43" value="">
```

Comment: а перенос ?.........

Comment: @MaximLensky: похоже, что автору вопроса он не нужен.

Comment: @UModeL это вообще как то не то - ни на одном сайте мира нету такого

Comment: @MaximLensky: да, такое только у нас! Только сегодня! Два по цене одного! Налетай!!! )))

Comment: @UModeL я ваще люблю юмор - но прикинь текст в 1000 символов - его не видно будет - надо перенос и сделать минимальный размер - типа того

Comment: @MaximLensky: может у автора 100К разрешение и диагональ метров 50 ))

Comment: @UModeL юморист :))

Comment: Автор поста не дал подробностей, а я со своей стороны всего лишь предоставил пример, как пищу для размышлений)

Comment: @UModeL я у svg заметил одну черту - хочешь поделюсь ?

Comment: @frozencoast : да мы только ЗА ! Хороший вариант, имеет право на жизнь. Опять же, мало инфы.

Comment: @UModeL https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/BaoGXKL  в css есть .item-svg - поставь ему box-shadow: 0 0 30px #000 - посмотри что будет

Comment: @MaximLensky: поподробнее, пжлст.

Comment: @UModeL поставь box-shadow и смотри на обрезанную картинку - здание залезет на неё

Comment: @MaximLensky: всё верно не залезает, а просвечивает, ибо это `BOX-shadow`, т.е. для коробочки. Чтобы тень повторяла контуры, надо использовать `filter: drop-shadow(0 0 30px #000);` ;-)

Comment: @UModeL там снизу - чуть чуть залазиет здание - дроп-шадоу не то

Comment: @MaximLensky : такое впечатление, что или паддинг у див, или марджин у свг. Думаю, что это повод задать вопрос. А лишние комменты здесь потереть.

Comment: спасибо огромное за помощь! Перенос был нужен, но и без него не хуже чем было, вот только я не смог этот код в сайт воткнуть, но думаю если покапаюсь - разберусь. Пока залил вариант @UModeL. А вообще низкий поклон Вам, даже и не думал что кто то поможет)

Если правила ресурса не запрещают, приложу ниже ссылку на свой проект)

Comment: https://starmap-gift.ru/k/kons.html

Answer (score 3):

Вы не предоставили стили, неизвестно от чего отталкиваться. Модифицировал код по минимуму:

```js
/* Функция пересчёта размера шрифта */
function fGummaFontSize() {
  /* Увеличиваем размер шрифта, до появления прокрутки */
  while (this.scrollHeight <= this.clientHeight || this.scrollWidth <= this.clientWidth) {
    this.style.fontSize = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(this).fontSize) + 2 + "px";
  }
  /* Уменьшаем размер шрифта, пока прокрутка не исчезнет */
  while (this.scrollHeight > this.clientHeight || this.scrollWidth > this.clientWidth) {
    this.style.fontSize = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(this).fontSize) - 1 + "px";
  }
}

/* Функция обхода всех элементов с нужным классом */
function fGummaResizeAll() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".gumma").forEach(el => fGummaFontSize.call(el));
}

window.onload = fGummaResizeAll; // Запуск после загрузки контента
window.onresize = fGummaResizeAll; // Запуск при изменении размеров окна и контейнеров
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; } body { background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png") 0% 0% no-repeat rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 100vh; display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; justify-content: space-around; justify-content: space-evenly; align-items: center; }

 /* Большая часть свойств критически важна! */
.gumma {
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  word-break: normal;
  line-break: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: none;
  hyphens: none;
  height: 160px;
  width: 30%;
  background: rgba(240, 240, 240);
}
```

```html
<div class="gumma" id="id_div">
  Тут текст должен менять размер в зависимости от кол-ва букв
</div>

Сюда мы его вводим: <input type="text" name="tekst" size="43" value="" onKeyUp="document.getElementById('id_div').innerHTML = (this.value||'&nbsp;'); fGummaResizeAll();">
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Все работает прекрасно, стили я сам сделаю)
Но есть одно НО, если удалить все буквы из инпута то код виснет намертво и больше ничего не дает написать, может есть какая то защита от этого? Буду еще более благодарен!)

Comment: @АлександрГорячев: да, я знаю об этом. Дополнил.

Comment: Вы лучший! Еще раз большое спасибо! Если понадобится необычный подарок - https://starmap-gift.ru/k/kons.html Сделаем вам скидку 50%