# Динамический Font-size

Tags: javascript, css, svg, шрифты

У меня есть несколько блоков одной ширины, например 300px. Каждый блок содержит одно слово с разным количеством букв(от 2 до 10). Как мне сделать так чтобы font-size у этого слова подстраивался и занимал 100% ширины блока, т.е. 300px. Высота блока может быть резиновой и не имеет значения. Пробовал через SVG тег , но там надо явно указывать font-size. Не могу придумать как, но может можно просчитать через calc CSS или функции SASS, но нужно без jQuery. Заранее спасибо! Может как-то поможет, но каждый блок - компонент React.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1128094/265406

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1084428/265406

Comment: UModel, благодарю