# изменение размера шрифта в соответствии с размером блока, в котором выводится текст

Tags: javascript, шрифты, grid

подскажите как решить следующую ситуацию:

отрисовываю сетку (`display: grid;`) в которой в некоторых ячейках еще сетка и во всех ячейках есть какой-то текст

для фиксированного размера сетки подобрал нужный размер шрифта и теперь хотелось бы задать его так, чтобы для любого размера сетки он масштабировался, т.е. если я задаю размер блока с сеткой в `1000px`, то текст занимает половину ячейки, если задаю размер блок `100vw` или `100px` все равно текст занимает половину ячейки

что-то под вечер с этими `em`, `rem` подзапутался :(

понятно, что указывать в пикселях и поинтах - это не вариант, но как тогда указать?

Comment: Ну есть еще `vw` и `wh` функции `calc()`, `min()`, `max()`, `minmax()`, `clamp()`, `fit-content()`, `repeat()`. Подсчет элементов `counter()` и `counters()`. Шрифтовые `character-variant()`, `styleset()`, `stylistic()`. И чисто математические `sin()`, `cos()`, `tan()`, `acos()`,`asin()`,`atan()`,`atan2()`, `sqrt()`, `hypot()`, `pow()`. Так что выбирайте https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-to-css-functions/ .

Comment: @DiD, а есть ли возможность задать высоту шрифта относительно размеров блока в котором шрифт выводится?

Comment: Думаю, что самое правильное решение, в рамках поставленной задачи - это использование SVG для текста.

Comment: Можете ещё глянуть такие решения на JS - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1128014/265406