# Автоматически отрегулировать размер шрифта, чтобы текст влезал в div

Tags: html, css

Есть div, который создается динамически.
Этот div создается поверх картинки, поэтому его позиция в absolute, и его высота и ширина, а так позиция - в процентах, чтобы не двигаться относительно картинки.

```
 <div style="font-size: 17px; color: black; background-color: white; position: absolute; bottom: @coordY;left: @coordX; transform: translate(-50%, 50%); width: @width; height: @height">@texts.Text</div>
```

Вопрос в следующем - как сделать так, чтобы текст всегда точно влезал в div? Чтобы его font-size регулировался в зависимости от количества текста и размеров div?

К примеру - текста 100 символов, размер div - 5% на 10%, и оно вычисляет font-size, чтобы все 100 символов влезли в этот div 5% на 10%, и это сохраняется при изменении размера окна браузера.

Вроде бы fit-content должен делать что-то похожее, но судя по офф докам https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content

это скорее ресайзит размер родительского элемента, чтобы в него влезли все дочерние. Мне же нужно наоборот - дочерний впихнуть в родительский, посредством подгонки размера шрифта.

Comment: Только три варианта: 1) вычислять с помощью JS; 2) задавать размер шрифта в `vh/vw`; 3) использовать для вывода текста SVG.

Comment: Возможно заинтересует или натолкнёт на мысль - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1084428/265406

Comment: @UModeL 2 вариант не подойдёт - от размеров вьюпорта конечно зависит размер шрифта, но он зависит еще и от количества текста и размера родительского элемента. А первый и третий вариант можно пожалуйста оформить как ответ, с примерами?